# Один и тот же запрос в phpMyAdmin выдает - 2 строки, а в коде php - 0

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Запрос спокойно работает в phpMyAdmin, при выполнении его на php выводит 0 строк. Уже пытался ввести данные сразу в запросе, не используя переменных, результат тот же. Пробовал запрос с кавычками одинарными, двойными, без кавычек. Как лечить? Для лучшей читабельности вот запрос -

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT `id_reysa` FROM `Reys` WHERE `otkuda`=
(SELECT `id_aeroporta` FROM `Aeroporti` WHERE `gorod` = "Москва") and `kuda`=
(SELECT `id_aeroporta` FROM `Aeroporti` WHERE `gorod` = "Лос-Анджелес")) as reyses
```

Код:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT `id_reysa` FROM `Reys` WHERE `otkuda`=(SELECT `id_aeroporta` FROM `Aeroporti` WHERE `gorod` = \"".$search_from."\") 
and `kuda`=(SELECT `id_aeroporta` FROM `Aeroporti` WHERE `gorod` = \"".$search_to."\")) as reyses";

/*$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Reys`"; -этот запрос работает, выводит 2 строки*/

if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql))
{
    echo "Запрос: " . $sql . "\n";
    echo "Номер_ошибки: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
    echo "Ошибка: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
    exit;
}

if($result->num_rows===0)
{
    echo $result->num_rows; //Выводит 0
    exit;
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    print_r($row);
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Это таблица рейсов:

[image: таблица рейсов]

Это таблица аэропортов:

[image: таблица аэропортов]

Comment: Проверьте содержимое переменной `$sql` после подстановки в неё значений. А ещё лучше перепишите эту дикость с подзапросами на вульгарный JOIN двух копий таблицы аэропортов.

Comment: @Akina , выводит тот же самый запрос, что я и написал, потом ввел его в phpMyAdmin и он работает прекрасно.

Comment: @Akina , изменил в запросе otkuda = '1' и kuda = '2' и все заработало, но мне надо все-таки как и было.

Comment: Тогда проверьте что-то типа ``SELECT `id_aeroporta` FROM `Aeroporti` WHERE `gorod` = "Лос-Анджелес"`` - возвращается ли запись? подозреваю, что у Вас проблемы с передачей из PHP кириллицы...

Comment: @Akina 0 строк, возможно вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

Вставил в код одну строку и все заработало. Была проблема с передачей из PHP кириллицы, как и сказал @Akina. Спасибо за помощь!

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```